# Is there a way to distinguish between clones in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am developing a game in unity, the main thing in the game is a tower.

The tower is built of 1000 Cubes. Each time that the player's shot hits the tower, it moves 1 unit down in the y axis.

I want to improve performance by making only the first 30 gameObjects (the first 30 cubes) Active and the rest Not Active.

How can I distinguish between the first 30 cubes and the rest because I don't know anything about the Not Active objects (After I make it Not Active the script on them is Not Active either and can not send information about each one of the clones).

I already tried to instantiate each cube after a certain y the tower hits but it was a problem because the tower is rotating and I can not instantiate exactly where the cubes are supposed to be.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure about what are you asking for, but I would suggest you to remove script attachment with every cube and make empty game object called something like **Event Handler**.

## Method 1

Then you can refactor your code to move inactive cubes within script attached to this empty object. You will find inactive cubes using **Resources.FindObjectsOfTypeAll()**.

## Method 2

Before setting off your cube (making it inactive) simply make a reference to it. Save all those cubes in some kind of list/array or something.